# Microsoft Azure Translator using like google Translator dropdown for html page

Tags: azure, google-translate, microsoft-translator

How do I use Microsoft Azure Translator using like Google Translator dropdown for html page?

I have an API Key of Microsoft Azure Translator.

Here is the sample screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) tl;dr you have to show your work and ask a specific question. Also: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I use Microsoft Azure Translator like Google Translator dropdown for HTML pages?

You can use the HTML code below to translate the text from one language to another using Microsoft Translator.

**Code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Microsoft Text Translator</title>
        <!-- Include jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Microsoft Text Translator</h1>
        <p>Translate text from one language to another:</p>
        <label for="fromLang">From Language:</label>
        <select id="fromLang">
            <option value="en">English</option>
            <option value="es">Spanish</option>
            <option value="fr">French</option>
            <!-- Add more language options as needed -->
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="toLang">To Language:</label>
        <select id="toLang">
            <option value="es">Spanish</option>
            <option value="en">English</option>
            <option value="fr">French</option>
            <!-- Add more language options as needed -->
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="text">Text to Translate:</label>
        <textarea id="text" rows="1" cols="30" placeholder="Enter text to translate"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button id="translateBtn">Translate</button>
        <br>
        <label for="output">Translation:</label>
        <textarea id="output" rows="1" cols="30" readonly></textarea>
    
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#translateBtn").click(function () {
                    var fromLang = $("#fromLang").val();
                    var toLang = $("#toLang").val();
                    var text = $("#text").val();
                    var apiKey = "xxxxx";
                    var url = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=" + fromLang + "&to=" + toLang;
                    var location = "xxxxx";
    
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: "POST",
                        beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
                            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey);
                            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region", location);
                        },
                        data: JSON.stringify([{ Text: text }]),
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#output").val(data[0].translations[0].text);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In the above you need **`API Key and location`** of Microsoft Azure Translator.

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Translator - Translate - REST API (Azure Cognitive Services) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/translator/translator/translate?tabs=HTTP#translate-success-example)

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are just a requirement. See [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)